# Celery - Querying Sqlite DB during task

Tags: javascript, python, flask, celery

I have a Python based flask app where I am using the Celery task queue to handle a set of e-mail tasks. I would like the Celery task to be able to query a sqlite database that I have tied into the whole app to pull in and use certain data but I keep getting this following error. If I pull out the one line in the celery task that queries my SQLite database, the task then executes without throwing this error so my assumption is that I am making a fundamental error regarding tying celery and my database together.

```
[2015-07-18 21:36:25,168: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:6657 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2015-07-18 21:36:25,187: ERROR/MainProcess] Task app.views.send_mail_task[4c3d5b1a-5ac3-4ab8-b633-b925eba5dd02] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1171, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

The relevant code is as follows:

**models.py**

```
...

class Company(Model):
  dont_contact_anymore = BooleanField(default=False)
  company_name = CharField()
  website = CharField(unique=True)
  email_address = CharField()
  country = CharField()
  scraped_on = DateTimeField(formats="%m-%d-%Y")
  have_contacted = BooleanField(default=False)
  current_pipeline_phase = IntegerField(default=0)


  sector = CharField()
  contacted_by = ForeignKeyField(
    rel_model=User,
    related_name='contacted_by',
    db_column='contacted_by'
    )

  class Meta:
    database = DATABASE
    order_by = ('have_contacted',)

  @classmethod
  def create_company(cls, company_name, website, email_address):
    try:
      with DATABASE.transaction():
        cls.create(company_name=company_name, website=website, email_address=email_address, scraped_on=datetime.now)
        print 'Saved {}'.format(company_name)
    except IntegrityError:
      print '{} already exists in the database'.format(company_name)

...
```

**celery.js**

```
function start_the_magic() {
  //Get the ids of the companies to contact and remove
  var ids = get_the_ids();

  var contact = ids[0]
  var remove = ids[1]

  console.log(contact);
  console.log(remove);

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/email_task',
      data: JSON.stringify({contact: contact, remove: remove}),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, status, request) {
          status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
          update_progress(status_url, '#progress div');
      },
      error: function() {
          alert('Unexpected error');
      }
  });
}


function update_progress(status_url, status_div) {
  // send GET request to status URL
  $.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
      // update UI
      percent = parseInt(data['current'] * 100 / data['total']);
      //Remove the table and install the progress bar
      $('div.progress-container').html("");
      $('div.progress-container').html(bootstrap_progress);
      $(status_div).text(percent + '%');
      if (data['state'] != 'PENDING' && data['state'] != 'PROGRESS') {
          if ('result' in data) {
              // show result
              console.log('update progress worked!');
              // $(status_div.childNodes[3]).text('Result: ' + data['result']);
          }
          else {
              // something unexpected happened
              console.log('something unexpected happened');
              // $(status_div.childNodes[3]).text('Result: ' + data['state']);
          }
      }
      else {
          // rerun in 2 seconds
          setTimeout(function() {
              update_progress(status_url, status_div);
          }, 2000);
      }
  });
}
```

**view.py**

```
...

@celery.task(base=DbTask, bind=True)
def send_mail_task(self, contact, remove):
    total_contact_companies = len(contact);
    verb = ['Starting up', 'Booting', 'Repairing', 'Loading', 'Checking']
    adjective = ['master', 'radiant', 'silent', 'harmonic', 'fast']
    noun = ['solar array', 'particle reshaper', 'cosmic ray', 'orbiter', 'bit']
    message = ''

    for num,i in enumerate(contact):
      company = Company.select().where(Company.id == i).get()

      **^This is the line where things are failing^**

      print 'Contacting ' + company
      message = 'E-mailing {} at {}...'.format(company.company_name, company.email_address)

      self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                          meta={'current': num, 'total': total_contact_companies,
                                'status': message})
      time.sleep(3)
    return {'current': 100, 'total': 100, 'status': 'Task completed!',
            'result': 42}

....
```

Essentially the error is being triggered when I try to query my Sqlite database within the celery task.

```
company = Company.select().where(Company.id == i).get()
```

Also, I am using Redis database for Celery.

**Update**

Here is a more verbose trace from the Celery log:

```
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,326: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.views.send_mail_task[acff718c-a5e3-430c-96d7-789d969cdb4f]
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,328: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x10bf07aa0> (args:('app.views.send_mail_task', 'acff718c-a5e3-430c-96d7-789d969cdb4f', [[u'1869', u'1870', u'1871'], []], {}, {'utc': True, u'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, u'group': None, 'args': [[u'1869', u'1870', u'1871'], []], 'retries': 0, u'delivery_info': {u'priority': 0, u'redelivered': None, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, u'hostname': 'celery@JoeyOrlandoMacBookAir.local', 'task': 'app.views.send_mail_task', 'callbacks': None, u'correlation_id': u'acff718c-a5e3-430c-96d7-789d969cdb4f', 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, u'reply_to': u'58c6e8a9-cab4-3f00-aacd-d761a3550934', 'id': 'acff718c-a5e3-430c-96d7-789d969cdb4f', u'headers': {}}) kwargs:{})
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,331: WARNING/Worker-1] this line will eventually get replaced with the company name that is getting contacted
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,332: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: app.views.send_mail_task[acff718c-a5e3-430c-96d7-789d969cdb4f] pid:44579
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,336: DEBUG/Worker-1] ('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."dont_contact_anymore", "t1"."company_name", "t1"."website", "t1"."email_address", "t1"."country", "t1"."scraped_on", "t1"."have_contacted", "t1"."current_pipeline_phase", "t1"."day_0_message_id", "t1"."day_0_response", "t1"."day_0_sent", "t1"."day_5_message_id", "t1"."day_5_response", "t1"."day_5_sent", "t1"."day_35_message_id", "t1"."day_35_response", "t1"."day_35_sent", "t1"."day_125_message_id", "t1"."day_125_response", "t1"."day_125_sent", "t1"."batch", "t1"."sector", "t1"."contacted_by" FROM "company" AS t1 WHERE ("t1"."id" = ?) ORDER BY "t1"."have_contacted" ASC LIMIT 1', [1869])
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,717: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:44579 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2015-07-19 21:13:46,730: ERROR/MainProcess] Task app.views.send_mail_task[acff718c-a5e3-430c-96d7-789d969cdb4f] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1171, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

**Update #2 with celery rdb function**

```
~$ telnet localhost 6903
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/app/views.py(107)send_mail_task()
-> company = Company.select().where(Company.id == i).get()
(Pdb) n
Connection closed by foreign host.
wyssuser@joeyorlcbookair:~$ telnet localhost 6902
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/app/views.py(107)send_mail_task()
-> company = Company.select().where(Company.id == i).get()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(4092)select()
-> @classmethod
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(4094)select()
-> query = SelectQuery(cls, *selection)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2536)__init__()
-> def __init__(self, model_class, *selection):
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2537)__init__()
-> super(SelectQuery, self).__init__(model_class)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2328)__init__()
-> def __init__(self, model_class):
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2329)__init__()
-> super(Query, self).__init__()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(376)__init__()
-> def __init__(self):
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(377)__init__()
-> self._negated = False
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(378)__init__()
-> self._alias = None
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(379)__init__()
-> self._bind_to = None
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(380)__init__()
-> self._ordering = None  # ASC or DESC.
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(380)__init__()->None
-> self._ordering = None  # ASC or DESC.
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2331)__init__()
-> self.model_class = model_class
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2332)__init__()
-> self.database = model_class._meta.database
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2334)__init__()
-> self._dirty = True
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2335)__init__()
-> self._query_ctx = model_class
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2336)__init__()
-> self._joins = {self.model_class: []}  # Join graph as adjacency list.
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2337)__init__()
-> self._where = None
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2337)__init__()->None
-> self._where = None
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2538)__init__()
-> self.require_commit = self.database.commit_select
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2539)__init__()
-> self.__select(*selection)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2621)__select()
-> def __select(self, *selection):
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2622)__select()
-> self._explicit_selection = len(selection) > 0
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2623)__select()
-> selection = selection or self.model_class._meta.get_fields()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3932)get_fields()
-> def get_fields(self):
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3933)get_fields()
-> return [f[1] for f in self.get_sorted_fields()]
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3925)get_sorted_fields()
-> def get_sorted_fields(self):
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3926)get_sorted_fields()
-> key = lambda i: i[1]._sort_key
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3927)get_sorted_fields()
-> return sorted(self.fields.items(), key=key)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3926)<lambda>()
-> key = lambda i: i[1]._sort_key
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3926)<lambda>()->(2, 42)
-> key = lambda i: i[1]._sort_key
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3927)get_sorted_fields()->[('id', <peewee....1228f910>), ('dont_contact_anymore', <peewee....12289e50>), ('company_name', <peewee....1228f190>), ('website', <peewee....1228f1d0>), ('email_address', <peewee....1228f210>), ('country', <peewee....1228f250>), ...]
-> return sorted(self.fields.items(), key=key)
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3933)get_fields()
-> return [f[1] for f in self.get_sorted_fields()]
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3933)get_fields()
-> return [f[1] for f in self.get_sorted_fields()]
(Pdb) s
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3933)get_fields()
-> return [f[1] for f in self.get_sorted_fields()]
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(3933)get_fields()->[<peewee....1228f910>, <peewee....12289e50>, <peewee....1228f190>, <peewee....1228f1d0>, <peewee....1228f210>, <peewee....1228f250>, ...]
-> return [f[1] for f in self.get_sorted_fields()]
(Pdb) r
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2624)__select()
-> self._select = self._model_shorthand(selection)
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2624)__select()->None
-> self._select = self._model_shorthand(selection)
(Pdb) r
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2540)__init__()
-> self._from = None
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(2554)__init__()->None
-> self._qr = None
(Pdb) r
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(4095)select()
-> if cls._meta.order_by:
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /Users/wyssuser/Desktop/new_danish/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py(4097)select()-><class '...d" ASC []
-> return query
(Pdb) r
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: What happens if you run the task directly from the interpreter with `task_instance.apply`?

Comment: Also, do you get any useful messages if you run the worker with `-l DEBUG`?

Comment: See the updated post details, I am still getting an error but with a bit more detail now that I am using the loglevel=DEBUG

Comment: Can you put in an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and see where it fails? I'm beginning to suspect that it's the SQLite driver that's segfaulting, but I wouldn't know why.

Comment: @Ming I used celery's rdb function from the contrib module, see the above rdb trace. It fails on the return query step it appears. Excuse my lack of experience with pdb, I'm relatively new to it.